# White squares when using plotmath expressions

Tags: r, macos, fonts, plotmath

Whenever I try to use symbols in a plotmath expression in R, I get white squares. For example, when I run `demo(plotmath)`, I get the following.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem may lie? I am using R 3.4.1 in Rstudio on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

[image]

---

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, it seems to be an issue with my fonts.
When I look at Symbol, I have two "Symbol Regular"s,  and the second one appears as question marks when viewing both together. However, when I click on the second one individually, the fonts appear normally. I tried to validate fonts and remove duplicates, but Font Book did not detect any problems. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you go to `Fontbook.app` and examine the Symbol font, is it perhaps duplicated or can you see any other evidence of corruption?

Comment: @42- Thanks very much, it does seem to be an issue with the Symbol font. I listed what I see above; do you know what I should do with the font to fix it?

Comment: Delete it. It will get replaced from some magic Apple storeroom buried deep in the bowels of the System.

Comment: @42- Thanks very much, everything works now! If you wish to post your comments as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to Fontbook.app and examine the Symbol font, is it perhaps duplicated or can you see any other evidence of corruption? – 42- 25 mins ago

@42- Thanks very much, it does seem to be an issue with the Symbol font. I listed what I see above; do you know what I should do with the font to fix it? – angryavian 9 mins ago

Delete it. It will get replaced from some magic Apple storeroom buried deep in the bowels of the System.

I don't know how this happens, but it used to happen to me fairly often. Doesn't seem to be happening lately. I remain puzzled. I'm guessing there  may be answers at `Ask Different` (but I didn't find an answer.) Whatever the mechanism it's been around for a long, long time:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031025010930633